# My iphone app is having memory problems and eventually crashes - uses a lot of images

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management

I am new to programming (learned how to write apps a few months ago) and recently wrote an app that crashes every time after about 5 minutes with several 'Received memory warning. Level=1' warnings.  While testing with instruments, I have been unable to detect any leaks and I'm fairly confident I'm releasing the objects correctly so I suspect the memory problems stem from the large number of png images I use (around 80).  I've tried changing from the -imageNamed method to -imageWithContentsOfFile and saw no real improvement.  If anyone could offer any tips I would really appreciate it since I am completely stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I tried cutting down my image use a bit and I really don't think I can cut anymore without really reducing the quality of the app. However, I'm still getting memory warnings and then an eventual crash. What confuses me is that I don't get a crash until about the 15th level of my game and there are no new images introduced between levels. I still haven't found any leaks (I used instruments and NSZombiesEnabled) so I don't think that's the problem. Could it be that I'm not pushing my view controllers right or something? I'm stumped.... Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Wasn't the point of `NSZombies` that memory is actually *not* given back so the zombie can complain it is being called after the official dealloc? It would explain the memory warnings. The way to solve this class of problems is to put some piece of code in a loop, e.g. do the *same* level 100 times, and see if the memory footprint increases with every time you do that same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running out of memory does not *necessarily* imply memory leaks. It could mean that you've asked for too much memory at once. In your case, you're probably trying to create too many `UIImage` objects that all exist simultaneously. Without seeing a lot more of your code, there's not much to say except try and find a way to use fewer images at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly `UIImage`s which you load using `imageNamed` offload their contents when possible, if they receive memory warnings. [UIImage Reference, see Images and Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) That would leave only a very small, empty `UIImage` container. So I suspect that you have some other problem.

Check for any loop within your program and make sure it doesn't leak in some way.

Answer (score 0):

also remember that PNGs on disk are much smaller than the corresponding image in memory. if your PNGs are large, you could just be using up too much memory. maybe you can delay-load images to make your footprint smaller.